# left shift count >= width of type in VC10, but not in VC13

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I wrote the following macro:

```
#define SetParam(PARAM, VALUE3, VALUE2, VALUE1) (((0x00000000000000000000000000000000 | PARAM) << 24) | (VALUE3 << 16) | (VALUE2 << 8) | (VALUE1))
```

In <strike>Visual Studio 2010</strike> Atmel Studio I get the error in the question, but in Visual Studio 2013 I do not get the error (both cpp projects). Was there a change in these two versions?

Or did I simply miss a configuration?

Furthermore, can I be sure that I get the correct result from the 2010-version (after I get some warnings)?

(Example) usage would be:

```
f(SetParam(0xb1, 0x01, 0xe1, 0x00));
```

with `f()` another function.

I apologize for making first wrong assumptions, but I thougth that the Atmel Studio is just an extended version of MSVC2010. It appearently isn't, and it is using GCC4.8.1, so that might be causing the error.

Comment: You're aware that `0x00000000000000000000000000000000 | PARAM` is equivalent to `PARAM`?

Comment: How did you use that macro to get the warning. Specifically, what are the types of `PARAM` and `VALUE*`?

Comment: @molbdnilo: Now after you tell me that I am seeing it, too....

Comment: @Wintermute: Question updated, `PARAM` and `VALUE*` are hex values

Comment: Also `0x00000000000000000000000000000000 << 24` is just `0x0 << 24`... which is just `0x0`

Comment: @Cyber: Only if param is equal to zero, otherwise afaik not. Am I correct?

Comment: Hm. I could see how a buggy compiler that's confused about integral promotions might complain about this with `short` or `char` values, and I could definitely see this break down with more complex expressions as parameters because there are no parentheses around the macro parameters in the macro body, but for plain integer values this should only break if `sizeof(int) == 2` (which it isn't with MSVC).

Comment: @arc_lupus Does the compiler complain about the example you posted? (And "hex value" is not a type, it's a form of integer literal.)

Comment: @molbdnilo: Yes, the compiler complains with the error posted in the question, but only in msvc2010.

Comment: @arc_lupus My VS 2010 doesn't warn about `f(SetParam(0xb1, 0x01, 0xe1, 0x00));` even with all warnings enabled. (`f` defined as `void f(int) {}`.) I think you need to post a complete example that exhibits the error.

Comment: By the way, 0x00000000000000000000000000000000 == 0x0 == 0.  You can save yourself some typing time.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Appearently I was mistaken by assuming the Atmel Studio is msvc2010, but after rechecking I saw that it is using gcc4.8.1, and therefore this might be causing the problem.

Comment: It is telling you that the *int* type for the target processor you selected has less than 24 bits.  Not uncommon for Atmel of course.   You could try `0L` instead.

Comment: The macro seems to assume that just because `0x00000000000000000000000000000000` is written in a particularly long form, its type is going to be anything other than `int`.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: It tells me the same when I remove the zeros completely

Comment: @HansPassant: How do I tell the macro that? Even if I remove the zeros completely I get the error (I should tell him that it has to expect uint32_t values instead of uint8_t)

Comment: Another way is by using a cast, (uint32_t)PARAM